# React: TypeError: Unable to get property 'handler' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React.js and cannot seem to get any event handlers to work.  I get the above-referenced error anytime I make an event handler outside of the render function instead of as an annonymous inner class.  Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong please?

```
class Checkboxes extends Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { checked: [true, true],
                    frame: [values, values],
                    title: ['A', 'B'] };

    this.handleChange= this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

handleChange(e) {
    let index= e.target.id;
    let newState = this.state.checked.slice();
    newState[index] = !this.state.checked[index];
    this.setState ({checked: newState});
}


render(){

    const selectionBoxes = this.state.title.map(function(title, index) {
        return (
            <div className="w3-checkbox" id={index} onClick={this.handleChange}> 
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            label={'Division '+title}
            value={this.state.checked[index]}
            checked={!this.state.checked[index]}
            onChange= {this.handleChange}
            id={index} />
        <label id={index} onClick={this.handleChange}> 
            {'Division '+ title}
        </label>
    </div>
                );
    });

    const frameDisplay = this.state.frame.map(function(frame, index) {
        return (
                <div>
                {this.state.checked[index]} ? null : 
                <DivFrame frameId={frame} width={this.state.width} height={this.state.height} title={this.state.title[index]} />
                </div>
                );
    });

    return (
            {selectionBoxes}
            );
 }
};

export default Checkboxes;
```

Comment: I cannot see any `handler` reference/access here.. Where does the error appear (which line)? Please mark it within your question. Thanks.

Comment: I apologize for trying to make the point in the title that the error is referring to my event listener.  The error is occurring on the line: '<div className="w3-checkbox" id={index} onClick={this.handleChange}>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that, even though you may have bound the `handleChange` to `this` in the constructor, it is still not in scope within the `this.state.title.map(function(title, index) {...` function. I have fixed this problem by simply changing `this.state.title.map(function(title, index) {...` to `this.state.title.map((title, index) => {...`

This is the ES6 syntax and does the binding for me automatically.

Have a look here for a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/py2zp8z1kj

Please note that for the sake of simplicity I have removed the code pertaining to the frames component since it's not really related to the problem and to cut down on the work required having to implement that component. To have the event handler working on that component as well though you will have to change the callback of the mapping function to the ES6 syntax as well.

Also, you will notice that in the `return` of the `render()` method, I have removed the curly braces because you do not need them since `selectionBoxes` is raw html and needs not to be evaluated. Actually evaluating it (`{ selectionBoxes}`) converts the value of `selectionBoxes` to an object which is NOT a valid react child. So rather put `selectionBoxes` as is in the render block.

In case you are not able to view the demo, this is how the code looks like:

```
 class Checkboxes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: [true, true],
      frame: [0, 1],
      title: ['A', 'B']
    };
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    let index = e.target.id;
    let newState = this.state.checked.slice();
    newState[index] = !this.state.checked[index];
    this.setState({ checked: newState });
  }


  render() {

    const selectionBoxes = this.state.title.map( (title, index) => {
      return (
        <div className="w3-checkbox" id={index} onClick={this.handleChange}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            label={'Division ' + title}
            value={this.state.checked[index]}
            checked={!this.state.checked[index]}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            id={index} />
          <label id={index} onClick={this.handleChange}>
            {'Division ' + title}
          </label>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
     selectionBoxes
    );
  }
};

export default Checkboxes;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Isn't the arrow syntax the same thing as the version that I had?  I need to wait to try it later because something is weird with the way this computer is serving up localhost:3000 so I'll let you know then if it solves my problem.  Also, you're correct about the frame state being unnecessary to this function.  I thought I had removed all the rest of the code that was unrelated to the problem.

Comment: As far as I understand, it is the same thing but for reason it this.handleChange loses scope within your mapping functions

Comment: If I were to try to have a parent render a checkbox, should the checkbox maintain it's own state (true/false) or can i somehow pass the true/false values through as props?  For some reason when I try to pass (true/false) values I get null on the object.

Comment: Always use `state` if the data kept in it has nothing to with any other component but the component possessing the `state` itself. If you need the values of that particular `state`in any other component, then simply pass them as `props`. If a parent component were to render the `Checkbox` component, then it would make much more sense to give control to the parent and simply pass how the behavior is to be for the child component through `props`

Comment: Based on that, I should pass the true/false value of the checkbox and checked status from parent state to this function as a prop.  The problem I run into is that I am unable to pass a boolean value as a prop.  Should I pass a string representing the boolean and have a function in the component to convert it to boolean?  Thank you very much for being willing to help me out with this.

Comment: No! Don't pass a string. You can do it like this: `<Checkbox isChecked={true} />`

Comment: I was apparently being an idiot and not passing the state correctly to the checkbox... or not having the checkbox report it's change appropriately.  Either way I got it working now.  Thank you again!